# Cant find azure monitor scheduled query with invalid data source

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

So Im using terraform to create a scheduled query alert on a particular application insight

```
resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "rule1" {
  name                = "queryrule${md5(format("%s-%s", var.resourcegroupname, var.name))}"  # This is the name of the deployment (has to be unique for each rule)
  resource_group_name = var.resourcegroupname
  template_body       = file("./modules/queryrule/queryRule.json")
  deployment_mode     = "Incremental"

  parameters = {
    action_emailSubject               = "${var.person} from ${var.email}"
    action_groups                     = "${join(";", var.action_group_array)}"
    action_trigger_thresholdOperator  = var.act_threshold_1operator
    action_trigger_threshold          = var.action_threshold
    name                              = var.name_rule
    description                       = var.description
    schedule_frequencyInMinutes       = var.frequency
    schedule_timeWindowInMinutes      = var.timeWindow
    query                             = var.queryString
    data_source_id                    = var.data_source
  }
}
```

queryRule.json is a normal ARM template for scheduled query.

THe problem is that when I deployed the terraform project the datasource was invalid so the scheduled query was created but not added the alert of the appinsight and also not added to the terraform state.

when I deployed next time it said this resource already exists but is not part of terraform state. I want to delete this scheduled query but i cant find it on the azure portal. Any ideas how to find and delete this orphan scheduled query?

Comment: Hello, Have you tried using CLI to list the scheduled queries present in your resource group where you had deployed the query using terraform and then delete it ? please refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/scheduled-query?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: no was not able to do use due to my account having low authroization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contacted Microsoft support to find the answer. The reason I was not able to find it because the scheduled query was never created, only the deployment for it was created and not added to terraform state. I had to go the the deployments option on menu on the resource group and found the failed deployment and deleted it.